# React Test Question: Write a react component that create a list of seven days of week and we can delete any random day of the week on click on it?

Tags: reactjs

How can we do this by class component or can we do it in another way?

Please suggest the best way to solve this question in reactjs either using function or class component.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [listItem, setListitem] = useState([
    "sun",
    "mon",
    "tue",
    "wed",
    "thur",
    "fri",
    "sat"
  ]);

  const deleteItem = (number) => {
    const newList = [...listItem];
    newList.splice(number, 1);
    setListitem(newList);
  };

  
  return (
    <div className = 'wrapper'>
    <ul>
      {listItem.map((day, i) => (
        <li>
          {day.toString()}
          <button id={day.toString()} onClick={() => deleteItem(i)}>
            Delete
          </button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: whatss issue in this, works fine, no issue at all

Comment: It's done in the function component. I also want to learn how to do it in the class component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in-class Component :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        listItem:[
            "sun",
            "mon",
            "tue",
            "wed",
            "thur",
            "fri",
            "sat"
        ],
      }
    // this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this); // this could be optional
    }
    
    deleteItem = (number) => {
        const newList = [...this.state.listItem];
        newList.splice(number, 1);
        this.setState({listItem:newList});
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div className = 'wrapper'>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.listItem.map((day, i) => (
                        <li>
                            {day.toString()}
                            <button id={day.toString()} onClick={() => this.deleteItem(i)}>
                                Delete
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: @Samira He like to know answer in both functional and class component

Comment: I edited my answer I catch it wrong. thanks @AshishKamble

Comment: please check my answer again @ShekharMourya

Comment: @Samira keep both answers, it helps new developers